# Add the users in Django Admin site into html table on webpage

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to capture the user data that is in the Django-Admin site and turn it into a html table. The problem that I am having is that my table is only displaying one user, which is the user that is logged in. I want to display the name of all of the users that are in the Django Admin database (Similar to a basketball roster). How can I accomplish that? Thank you.

Here is my views.py code:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from home.forms import HomeForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from home.models import Post


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'


    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(is_superuser=True)

        args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Here is the html template code:

```
  <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Player Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Position</th>
                    <th scope="col">Grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ user.userprofile.jersey_number }}</th>
                    <td>{{ user.get_full_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.userprofile.position }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.userprofile.grade }}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

[image: My Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any kind of for loop in your template, so naturally it will only show one user. You need to iterate over the `users` collection that you passed from the view.

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ user.userprofile.jersey_number }}</th>
        <td>{{ user.get_full_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.userprofile.position }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.userprofile.grade }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. I knew I was missing something small. I greatly appreciate it.